# animating gradient while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use jquery to animate a transparent menu into black when I scroll down? I am trying to use the scroll function, but I don't know how to animate the gradient.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
    <div id="text">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: fixed;
}

#text {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #31fa87;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(
){});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5gudwLs6/3/

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps!! ;) Jquery solution, checking with scrolltop the relative position with the size of the body element!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  $("#menu").css("opacity", $("body").scrollTop() / $("body").height());

});
```

```css
#menu {
  opacity: 0.0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
}
#text {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #31fa87;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
  </div>
  <div id="text">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just a note that javascript doesn't execute on some phones (read: iphones) while scrolling.  As soon as scrolling stops, javascript continues.

Comment: huh!! didn`t know  about that. Never animated on relation to scrolling!! Thanks for the tip!! +
Then maybe...
CSS dynamic calculations with  **calc();** ??

[doc for calc] (http://coboldinosaur.com/pages/css-calc-function.html)

Comment: You can't use `calc()` in relation to things like `scrollTop`.  The only solution is to use a javascript scroller like iScroll which performs its own calculations and is rapidly updates the CSS to *simulate* scrolling.  Just fair warning, iScroll isn't always a magic bullet and feels janky on older phones... but it's pretty f'ing cool once you get it working.

Comment: I was yesterday looking at that but desisted to find a css way of doing it with calc(). completely agree with you! thanks for the tip!!!